# Android - Two Actvities can't get Bundle Extras out of Nine

Tags: java, android, android-7.1-nougat

So I have 9 activities that started out as copy and pastes of each other. As far as I can tell they really only differ in the number of check boxes and text fields on them. Two of the activities can't receive Bundle Extras and it has me stumped. I can move freely between the 7 working activities but the last two wont receive Bundle Extras from any of the other activities.

The only information that is being passed about is one int.

Sender Example

```
myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PostSession.class);
output.putInt("flightId", mFlightInfoId);
startActivity(myIntent);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Receiver Example from one of the non-working activities

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
mFlightInfoId = extras.getInt("flightId");
```

Error Message

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{project.xyz.logging/project.xyz.logging.PostSession}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: one of them came without taking a data try to set data ("flightId", "likethis") not like this ("flightId", mFlightInfoId) force it with true data parse and check if the same error came or gone - if it gone try to know witch one not parse the data

Comment: There isn't enough information here for anyone to help. Please add the code for the activity which isn't getting the data and how you are sending it. Just looking from what you have right now, you never actually put the `output` bundle in the `myIntent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Napster said I forgot to put the output bundle into the Intent

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the below code. I recommend you to have a look [on this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8rd62Rv3r0):

```
mFlightInfoId = getIntent().getIntExtra("flightId");
```